# On clicking on Vf page button getting logged out in safari browser

Tags: visualforce, session, safari

I have created a vf button for list view/Detail page. When I click on it I am redirected to login page. I tried some things but was not able to find reason for it. Then I tried session setting.[image]

I disabled the "Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used" setting. Then when I refreshed and clicked on button in safari I was able to see vf page. ***Is it suppose to work this way***. I don't want to remove this session setting, how can my vf buttons still work in safari browser.

My Visualforce page is

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
testing
</apex:page>
```